# Vectr wont start: Illegal instruction (core dumped)

Tags: snap

I installed Vectr via snap

```
sudo snap install vectr
```

Install was success. But when I try to start the app nothing happens. Even tried through the terminal but that only gives me the error

```
Illegal instruction (core dumped)
```

i tried to download Vectr as zip file from their website and after I installed libgconf it started up. However the version from snap still wont start up.

Anyone else has this problem or can try it out? :)

Comment: Got the same issue, anyone have a fix yet?

Comment: Have a same problem, reinstalling with `--classic` or `--devmode` does **not** solve the issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duplicated on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS x86_64 (outputs are excerpted)

Run from the command line with strace, (`strace vectr example.svg`) produces:

> geteuid()                               = 1000  write(2, "need to run
>   as root or suid", 27need to run as root or suid) = 27

Run from the command line with sudo (`sudo vectr example.svg`) produces:

> mkdir: cannot create directory '/run/user/0': Permission denied
>   /snap/vectr/2/bin/desktop-launch: line 231: 11359 Segmentation fault
>   (core dumped)

If you turn the dial to '11' and run it as (`sudo strace vectr example.svg`), you'll see a very long string of `-1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)` errors scroll past, complaining mostly about libraries, which leads me to guess that there's a configuration error somewhere in this snap. It might be that the `line 231` error points a little more specifically at not being able to load gdk-pixbuf-2.0, but I'm not familiar enough with snaps to dig much further than that.

Comment: Why was this accepted? What solves the problem?

Answer (score 0):

AVX support not available in older CPU's - won't work.
Run in terminal:  $ more /proc/cpuinfo | grep flags

Advanced Vector Extensions (AVX) will not appear in older CPU's